# Convert Y-m-dTH:M:Sz to datetime to compare

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I have a string like `"2020-01-20T11:00:05-05:00"`, and I want to compare this with `datetime.now()` to see if it is greater than it.

I think I need to use `datetime.strptime(..., ...)` although I don't know what to do about the timezone bit.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** `date_time = datetime.strptime("2020-01-20T11:00:05-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`. This works, however now when I compare them I get `TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`.

**EDIT2:** Perhaps I need to make my `datetime.now()` timezone aware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated, it seems that link provides the information you need for the question. However I will add a full working example. Using `pytz` and `datetime`:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
if now < datetime.strptime("2020-01-21T11:00:05-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"):
    print("A")
else:
    print("B")
```

Output:

```
B
```

Changing the day to "10" to make sure the statime is `True`:

```
if now < datetime.strptime("2020-01-10T11:00:05-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"):
    print("A")
else:
    print("B")
```

Output:

```
A
```

Another option as Jason Whitman mentioned using `datetime.timezone.utc` changing the imports and using it will work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
if now < datetime.strptime("2020-01-21T11:00:05-05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"):
    print("A")
else:
    print("B")
```

Comment: Why `pytz.utc` rather than `datetime.timezone.utc`?

Comment: It is a valid answer too, I'll edit it adding it.